# Header as combo box in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is is possible to change just the header in a datagridview to be a combobox? I have data I am displaying that I wish the user to be able to change the header based on data within a combobox. I need to use a datagridview and keep the rest of my controls on my form the same. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can set a column header in a `DataGridView` to be a `ComboBox`, however it would be perfectly possible to use the `ComboBox` to apply a new `RowFilter` on the `DataGridView` when it is changed, which I'm guessing is the effect you're after.

Comment: I currently have 2 datagridviews. The top one controls current headers at allow for change, the bottom one updates based on the changes. This is dealing with datafiles that I am standardizing, and are built dynamically based on the data. I am trying to combine these controls into one control while still being able to preview the rest of the data.